# Unable to render the JSP using Spring Boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

i 'm new in spring boot and i wanted to start with a simple example however nothing seemed to work 
this my controller:

```
Package controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class testController {
RequestMapping("view/aboutus")
public String greeting(Model model) {
 model.addAttribute("name", "azertyyyy");
  return "aboutus";  }}
```

and this is the jsp view:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html> <body>  ${name}


 <p>hello world</p> </body></html>
```

i added the needed dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>


 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
```

and i added the prefix and suffix in application.properties

when i run the application only hello world is shown on the view without the name variable, after searching here i changed the view directory from src/main/webapp/view to src/main/resource/templates but spring boot couldn't find the view anymore

Comment: i can add some details if there's something not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you are fully aware of the changes we have to make when we want to run the application as war package.

1. Change the packing to war from jar and require dependencies.
2. Change the main application class to extend SpringBootServletInitializer and implement configure()
3. Define your jsp pages path in application properties
4. Put JSPs in correct path (webapp/WEB-INF/jsp check screen shot)

Directory Structure for the project

[image: Directory Structure]
Following is the code changes I have to done to run the JSP

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_Exception_Framework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Test_Exception_Framework</name>
    <description>Project to test ExceptionFramework</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Main Class

```
package com.exception;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }


}
```

Rest Controller - which redirects to JSP

```
package com.exception.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class TestExceptionController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {

        System.out.println("in controller");

        model.put("message", "hello spring boot");

        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

application.properties - define the path for JSPs

```
server.port=8085
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1)*** use spring version 2.0.3.RELEASE or less
2) add the dependency
     <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

3) this optional dependency

<!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>
```