# InteliiJ Idea SpringBoot web app problem - there is no configured/running web-servers found

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have the following problem - when in the jsp file I click on the web browser icon, the following message pops up: **"There is no configured/running web-servers found! Please run any web-configuration and hit the refresh button!"**

I have no idea what I can do with this problem, I'm working with SpringBoot I really need help with this. I don't know maybe it's some problem with run configuration? when I worked with thymeleaf before, there was no problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you search the web for this message? Almost certainly one of those hits gives you a place to start. If that doesn't help you should [edit] the question and say what you tried.

Comment: Please consider posting content of your `Application` that is  annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and your project structure.

Comment: Also, consider viewing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391915/how-to-render-jsp-using-spring-boot-application)